# How to pass file lines to tuple in Python?

Tags: python, class, tuples

I know this will sound similar to other questions but it differs a little bit.

I have this study script and what it does is generates questions, you have to choose an answer then it tells you you're right or wrong. This code could be made really small but I am not sure how to. The amount of questions will soon be in the 100s and the code will become unmanageable so what I want to do is put the questions, answers and correct answer into a file and pass it to the code to be executed. I have tried several variations to no avail.

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import random
import sys

class Question:
    def __init__(self, question, answers, correctAnswer):
        self.question = question
        self.answers = answers
        self.correct = correctAnswer

def askQuestion(self):
    print(self.question)

    for i in range(len(self.answers)):
        print('\t{}){}'.format(i, self.answers[i]))

    while True:
        try:
            answer = int(input('\nChoose your answer!>>> '))
            break
        except ValueError:
            print('Please type a number')
    return True if answer == self.correct else False

def score_func():
    final_score = score / 63.0 * 100.0
    if final_score >= 75:
        print('You\'re killin it!')
        print("Your score is %d percent!" % final_score)
    elif final_score >= 51:
        print('You passed but you could do better!')
        print("Your score is %d percent!" % final_score)
    elif final_score < 50:
        print('You failed, really you need to study bro...')
        print("Your score is %d percent!" % final_score)
    else:
        print('Something went wrong with the calculation of your score.')

questions = (
Question('How many bits are in a byte??', ('4','8','2'), 1),
Question('How many devices can be supported by a USB bus??', ('4','100','127'), 2),
Question('194.0.0.0 is in what Class of I.Ps?', ('A','B','1','C'), 3),
)

score = 0

for q in questions:
    if(q.askQuestion()):
        print('Correct! You\'re killin\' it!')
        score += 1
    else:
        print('You\'re wrong! You suck!!')

score_func()
quit()
```

I have tried a few different things such as:

```
 tuple([x.strip() for x in open('file.txt').readlines()])
```

or even a few really bad attempts such as:

```
 questions = []
text = with open('C:\\Users\\Arthur.J.A\\Desktop\\Jake\\Programming\\Python\\Code\\Study_Scripts\\MCSA-Study-Script.txt') as f:
for line in f line.append()
```

and a few others but everything either, passes the text file back to me as a string instead of tuples or it just jams everything together. I wonder if this is even possible to keep my tuples in a text file then pass it to my class functions.

NOTE: There will be indentation errors in this code because of the way I have to indent every line in Stack Overflow posts.

Comment: We need the evuentual exception and traceback that python gave you in order to know why your code would not work. Anyway your attempt: `tuple([x.strip() for x in open('file.txt').readlines()])` seems reasonable. Just make sure you open the file in text mode (by passing `'rt'` as second argument to `open()`). Then converting the list to a tuple is worthless, you can remove the surrounding `tuple()`. Also remember that the `file.txt` path will be relative to the current direcory (which is usually the current directory in the shell from which you are starting the python interpreter)

Comment: So if I just use it as a list it will work then?

Comment: C:\Users\Arthur.J.A>python C:\Users\Arthur.J.A\Desktop\Jake\Programming\Python\Code\Study_Scripts\MCSA-Study-Script.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Arthur.J.A\Desktop\Jake\Programming\Python\Code\Study_Scripts\MCSA-Study-Script.py", line 45, in <module>
    if(q.askQuestion()):
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'askQuestion'

This is what I get.
But I didn't get that with my original code.

Comment: ok then it's easy: your successfully read lines from your file, but do not convert them to `Question` objects.

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: Python 3. I have 2 and 3 at home but I am currently sitting at school on a Windows box instead of at home with my Linux Box which has all my packages and full scripts. I just have notepad, cmd and py3 here.

Comment: On this site, show your appreciation by upvoting all the useful answers. You do that by clicking the up-arrow at the top-left of the answer. In addition, accept the best answer (if it actually answers your question) by clicking the checkmark near the top-left of the answer. That is better than saying thanks in a comment or at the end of your question. It also helps others to see that your question was answered.

Comment: I did but it says something about my new profile not showing upvotes.
EDIT: it says because I have less then 15 reputation so it wont show. Sorry buddy.

Comment: The Markdown formatting system here should not break any of your indentation at all. If you indent all lines in a piece of code by one indent or more (four spaces) then the code will be block-formatted, and each line will have indentation equal to the number of indents minus one. Since the rules are the same for all lines, they will all indent equally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a `Question` class that is supposed be represent your questions, but you read strings from your file.txt
You need to find a way to convert those strings to Question objects. To do so, you need to choose a representation for those strings. You may use CSV as already suggested, but personnally I like JSON, it allows for a very simple parsing:

file.txt contents (add more questions as needed):

```
[
    {
        "question": "How many bits are in a byte??",
        "answers": ["4", "8", "2"],
        "correctAnswer": 1
    },
    {
        "question": "How many devices can be supported by a USB bus??",
        "answers": ["4","100", "127"],
        "correctAnswer": 2
    }
]
```

Code to read that file and convert it to Question objects:

```
import json

with open("file.txt", 'rt') as finput:
    questions = [Question(**args) for args in json.load(finput)]
```

Comment: Do you think this would effect my Class Functions?

Comment: Not at all. Once you have created your Question objects, then they will behave just like before

Comment: beautiful. Thank you I'll get back to you guys when I get home.

Comment: did you include leading `[` and trailing `]` in your file ?

Comment: I fixed it. Check out the edit of my main post. My profile is to new to upvote so it wont show, sorry.

Comment: Im getting a json decode error, with args do i need to call the file when I write the command to start the script in cmd or terminal. not sure hwy it worked last night but not now. It shouldn't since the text path has been hard coded into the script

Comment: Turns out it works fine with one question but with multiple different ones it shits the bed and gives me this huge error based on the json package, i checked it out but cant figure out the problem..

Comment: I edited my answer to include multiple questions in the JSON file. If you respect the JSON syntax and have the 3 fields `"question"`, `"answers"` and `"correctAnswer"` for each question, I don't see any reason why it would not work

Comment: It seems like it may be a json error... I already did the changes here is the error:

Comment: File "MCSA-Study-Script.py", line 43, in <module>
questions = (Question(**args) for args in json.load(finput))
File "C:\Users\Arthur.J.A\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\json\__init__.py", line 299, in load parse_constant=parse_constant, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook, **kw)
File "C:\Users\Arthur.J.A\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\json\__init__.py", line 354, in loads return _default_decoder.decode(s)

Comment: File "C:\Users\Arthur.J.A\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\json\decoder.py", line 342, in decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 5 column 6 (char 127)

Comment: Extra data probably means that you have unwanted characters at the end of the file

Comment: this is talking about the json decoder file i imported, its part of the python library 'json'

Answer (score 1):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

Thanks for all your contributions, this is what I decided to go with and works great:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import random
import sys
import json

class Question:
    def __init__( self, question, answers, correctAnswer ):
        self.question = question
        self.answers  = answers
        self.correct  = correctAnswer

def askQuestion( self ):
    print( self.question )

    for i in range( len( self.answers ) ):
        print( '\t{}){}'.format( i, self.answers[i] ) )

    while True:
        try:
            answer = int( input( '\nChoose your answer!>>> ' ) )
            break
        except ValueError:
            print( 'Please type a number' )
    return True if answer == self.correct else False

def score_func():
    global score
    final_score = score / 1.0 * 100.0
    if final_score >= 75:
        print( 'You\'re killin it!' )
        print( "Your score is %d percent!" % final_score )
    elif final_score >= 51:
        print( 'You passed but you could do better!' )
        print( "Your score is %d percent!" % final_score )
    elif final_score < 50:
        print( 'You failed, really you need to study bro...' )
        print( "Your score is %d percent!" % final_score )
    else:
        print( 'Something went wrong with the calculation of your score.' )

score = 0

with open( "C:\\Users\\Arthur.J.A\\Desktop\\Jake\\Programming\\Python\\Code\\Study_Scripts\\py1.txt", 'rt' ) as finput:
    questions = [Question( **args ) for args in json.load( finput )]


for q in questions:
    if( q.askQuestion() ):
        print( 'Correct! You\'re killin\' it!' )
        score += 1
    else:
        print( 'You\'re wrong! You suck!!' )

score_func()
quit()
```

And then for my text file it will be in the following format:

```
[   
    {
         "question": "How many bits are in a byte??",
         "answers": ["2", "4", "6", "8"],
         "correctAnswer": 3
     }
]
```

Thanks everyone for the help and again my indentation is probably off but ignore that. Code works spectacular.

Answer (score 0):

So some first thoughts at this:

I would strongly recommend a standard JSON file; and read that in to a list of Objects. This could look something like:

```
[
 {
    "question" : "How many bits are in a byte?",
    "answers" : [4, 8, 2],
    "correctAnswer" : 1
 },
 {
    "question" : "194.0.0.0 is in what Class of I.Ps?",
    "answers" : ["A", "B", "C"],
    "correctAnswer" : 2
 }
]
```

Alternatively; you could modify your text file to have key/values.

```
Q:How many bits are in a byte?
A:4,8,2
CA:1

Q:194.0.0.0 is in what Class of I.Ps?
A:A,B,C
CA:2
```

This would allow you to read the file like:

```
f = open('myfile.txt','r')

questions = []

for line in f:
    # Psuedocode
    if line.startswith("Q"):
        found question
    if line.startswith("A"):
        found answer
    if line.startswith("CA"):
        found correctAnswer

f.close()
```

Comment: I like this, Ill try it out later when I got a minute and let you know if it worked.

Comment: Fun, we are likeminded for the JSON representation ! :)

Comment: Do you two think I would have to modify my class to use either of your methods?

Comment: You shouldn't have to modify your class; as you pass each of the values in as parameters. You will just have to figure out the parsing out of each of your three parameters depending on the method you intend on implementing. Then it is just a matter of appending a new object to the list of questions.

Answer (score 0):

Note, `input` function is defferent in Python 2. In Python 2, you need to use `raw_input` instead. The classic way is as follow:

```
try:
    input = raw_input  # Python 2
except NameError:
    input = input  # Python 3
```

You can simplify the implementation of your `Question` class:

```
class Question(object):
    def __init__(self, question, answers, correct):
        self.question = question
        self.answers = answers
        self.correct = correct

    def ask(self):
        print(self.question)
        for pos, answer in enumerate(self.answers, 1):
            print('\t{0}) {1}'.format(pos, answer))
        count = len(self.answers)
        while True:
            try:
                answer = int(input('\nChoose your answer!>>> '))
                if 1 <= answer <= count:
                    break
            except ValueError:
                print('Please type a number between 1 and {0}'.format(count))
        return answer == self.correct
```

- You can use `enumarate` to iterate the `self.answer` attribute and get an index (here, I use a 1-based index for the *pos* variable).
- You can test if the answer is between 1 and the number of possible answers
- You can simplify the return value.

For a better design, you can define a `Questionnaire` class which store all the questions:

```
class Questionnaire(object):
    def __init__(self, questions):
        self.questions = questions

    def run(self):
        score = 0
        for question in self.questions:
            if question.ask():
                score += 1
        final_score = 100.0 * score / len(self.questions)
        if final_score >= 75:
            print('You\'re killin it!')
            print("Your score is %d percent!" % final_score)
        elif final_score >= 51:
            print('You passed but you could do better!')
            print("Your score is %d percent!" % final_score)
        elif final_score < 50:
            print('You failed, really you need to study bro...')
            print("Your score is %d percent!" % final_score)
        else:
            print('Something went wrong with the calculation of your score.')
```

- The score is initialized to 0 and increments every time an answer is right.

Instead of storing your question in a "flat" text file, you can use [JSON](http://www.json.org/).

- JSON format is human-readable,
- It support UNICODE characters by standard,
- The JSON format is well-structured and quite simple.

Parsing JSON file with Python is straightforward: Open the file in binary mode and parse it.

Here is an example:

```
{
    "questionnaire": [
        {
            "question": "– How many bits are in a byte?",
            "answers": [
                "4",
                "8",
                "2"
            ],
            "correct": 1
        },
        {
            "question": "– How many devices can be supported by a USB bus?",
            "answers": [
                "4",
                "100",
                "127"
            ],
            "correct": 2
        },
        {
            "question": "– 194.0.0.0 is in what Class of I.Ps?",
            "answers": [
                "A",
                "B",
                "1",
                "C"
            ],
            "correct": 3
        }

    ]
}
```

The following function parses this JSON file and construct a `Questionnaire` instance and a list of `Question`.

```
def load_from_json(path):
    with io.open(path, mode="rb") as fd:
        data = json.load(fd, encoding="utf-8")
    obj_list = data['questionnaire']
    questions = []
    for obj in obj_list:
        question = Question(obj['question'], obj['answers'], obj['correct'])
        questions.append(question)
    # -- Could also be done with a comprehension list:
    # self.questions = [Question(obj['question'], obj['answers'], obj['correct'])
    #                   for obj in obj_list]
    return Questionnaire(questions)
```

To use this `Questionnaire` instance, you can do as follow:

```
questionnaire = load_from_json("questionnaire.json")
questionnaire.run()
```

Comment: I know the differences between 2 and 3 I started with 2 which I liked better and have transitioned almost fully to 3

Answer (score 0):

You *could* use JSON for this, but it does add extra stuff to your data that you don't really need. Instead, we can use a simple CSV file. On each row of the file we have a question string, followed by some number of answer strings, followed by the number.

To make it easy to save your existing question data I've added a new method `aslist` to your `Question` class: it creates a list of the attributes of a `Question` instance. I've also given `Question` a `__str__` method and a `__repr__` method so we have two ways of displaying a `Question` instance.

Here's some code containing the new `Question` class, plus the code needed to save it to a CSV file. We also use the `__repr__` method to print the questions we're saving. I added an extra "fake" question to test that the CSV stuff behaves correctly. Of course, in the final program you should remove that fake data!

```
import csv

class Question:
    def __init__(self, question, answers, correctAnswer):
        self.question = question
        self.answers = answers
        self.correct = correctAnswer

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Question({!r}, {!r}, {!r})'.format(self.question, self.answers, self.correct)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}\n{}: {}\n'.format(self.question, self.answers, self.correct)

    def aslist(self):
        ''' Put question data into a single list '''
        return [self.question] + list(self.answers) + [self.correct]

fname = 'questions.txt'

questions = (
    Question('How many bits are in a byte??', ('4','8','2'), 1),
    Question('How many devices can be supported by a USB bus??', ('4','100','127'), 2),
    Question('194.0.0.0 is in what Class of I.Ps?', ('A','B','1','C'), 3),
    Question('''Testing various, 'tricky' "things" here''', ('A','B','C'), 0),
)

#Save old questions data.
with open(fname, 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    for q in questions:
        writer.writerow(q.aslist())
        print(repr(q))
```

**output**

```
Question('How many bits are in a byte??', ('4', '8', '2'), 1)
Question('How many devices can be supported by a USB bus??', ('4', '100', '127'), 2)
Question('194.0.0.0 is in what Class of I.Ps?', ('A', 'B', '1', 'C'), 3)
Question('Testing various, \'tricky\' "things" here', ('A', 'B', 'C'), 0)
```

**contents of 'questions.txt'**

```
"How many bits are in a byte??","4","8","2","1"
"How many devices can be supported by a USB bus??","4","100","127","2"
"194.0.0.0 is in what Class of I.Ps?","A","B","1","C","3"
"Testing various, 'tricky' ""things"" here","A","B","C","0"
```

As you can see, this is more compact than doing it with JSON, so it's a bit easier when you want to add more questions manually. The only thing you have to remember is to quote the number at the end of the line.

---

And now here's the code to read the data from 'questions.txt' into a new `questions` list. After we load it, we print it (using the `__str__` method), to make sure everything worked properly.

```
import csv

class Question:
    def __init__(self, question, answers, correctAnswer):
        self.question = question
        self.answers = answers
        self.correct = correctAnswer

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Question({!r}, {!r}, {!r})'.format(self.question, self.answers, self.correct)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}\n{}: {}\n'.format(self.question, self.answers, self.correct)

    def aslist(self):
        ''' Put question data into a single list '''
        return [self.question] + list(self.answers) + [self.correct]

fname = 'questions.txt'

questions = []
with open(fname, 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, skipinitialspace=True)
    for row in reader:
        q = Question(row[0], tuple(row[1:-1]), int(row[-1]))
        questions.append(q)

for q in questions:
    print(q)
```

**output**

```
How many bits are in a byte??
('4', '8', '2'): 1

How many devices can be supported by a USB bus??
('4', '100', '127'): 2

194.0.0.0 is in what Class of I.Ps?
('A', 'B', '1', 'C'): 3

Testing various, 'tricky' "things" here
('A', 'B', 'C'): 0
```

We pass `skipinitialspace=True` to the `csv.reader` so that we can put spaces after the commas in 'question.txt' if we want to.

Of course, once we've saved the old questions data we don't really need the `aslist` method anymore, but it doesn't hurt to leave it there. And who knows, it may come in handy one day. ;)

Comment: Sorry I'd rather not re-write that much code, it would no longer be my project. But thank you for putting in the hard work to answer! Looks good!

Comment: @Creeping-spyder No worries, I hope that you find this code helpful at some stage, even if you don't want to use it for your current project. FWIW, my code just shows how to save your current question data to a simple CSV file and load it back in again; so you should be able to use it in conjunction with your code that does the actual quiz stuff. But at least consider giving your custom classes a `__repr__` method. Even if you don't need it for the final program it can be very handy while developing & debugging: the default `__repr__` that gets inherited from `object` isn't very informative.

Comment: Perfect Ill try it with my next course when I want to make some more flashcards

Comment: actually I wrote it out and it does nothing but print my text file. you do realize the whole point was to ask a question and have the user answer it right? my oringinal script did this all perfectly i just wanted to take my tuple from an outside source thats it....

Comment: @Creeping-spyder As I said before, my code just shows how to save your current `questions` data to a simple CSV file, and how to load it back in again to a `questions` list from that CSV file. I didn't include any quiz-asking code because your question specifically asks about having the `questions` data in a file rather than having it hard-coded into the script, so that's what I've answered.